# D3.js data groups and transitions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transform, transition

Inspired by [Mike Bostock's Wealth of Nations,](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/) I'm trying to illustrate infection rates over time. I'm trying to group by Month and transition() a bubble along the x-axis (Month).

I'm stuck on grouping by Month...

I've edited this post significantly following helpful feedback from Lars and Christopher below.

A jsFiddle example here - [hhttp://jsfiddle.net/Nyquist212/JSsHL/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Nyquist212/JSsHL/1/)

```
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var json = 
    [
      {
        "Month":1,
        "VisitCount":894,
        "DiagnosisName":"ACUTE PHARYNGITIS"
      },
      {
        "Month":1,
        "VisitCount":807,
        "DiagnosisName":"PNEUMONIA ORGANISM NOS"
      },
      {
        "Month":2,
        "VisitCount":566,
        "DiagnosisName":"ACUTE PHARYNGITIS"
      },
      {
        "Month":2,
        "VisitCount":456,
        "DiagnosisName":"PNEUMONIA ORGANISM NOS"
      },
      {
        "Month":3,
        "VisitCount":273,
        "DiagnosisName":"ACUTE PHARYNGITIS"
      },
      {
        "Month":3,
        "VisitCount":189,
        "DiagnosisName":"PNEUMONIA ORGANISM NOS"
      }
    ]

   var svgContainer = d3.select("#chart")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("height", 250)
            .attr("width",750);

    var bubbleGroup = svgContainer.append("g");

    var bubble =  bubbleGroup.selectAll("circle")
            .data(json)
            .enter()
            .append("circle");

    var bubbleAttributes = bubble
            .style("stroke", "blue")
            .style("fill", "white")
            .attr("r", function(d){return (d.VisitCount/10);})
            .attr("cy", 150)
            .attr("cx", function(d){return (d.Month * 100);});

    d3.select("Body").selectAll("p")
            .data(json)
            .enter()
            .append("p")
            .text(function(d){return d.Month + " " + d.DiagnosisName + " " + d.VisitCount;})

    </script>
```

EDIT: Updated with corrections from Christopher Chiche

EDIT: Updated with partially working example as suggested by Lars Kotthoff

Comment: As Christopher said, at this point we'll need a complete working example (i.e. code + data).

Comment: Edited post with a JsFiddle link. I haven't used this before so hope I set it up right. Thanks for any time you might be able to spend looking at this...

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work for me -- for something that has several files, you may find http://plnkr.co/ more suitable.

Comment: You should try to come with an example as simple as possible showing what does not work. Chances are high that you will find your problem in the process.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. I stripped it right back to the bare bones and embedded some test json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a combination of [`d3.nest`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_nest) and a transition loop for this. Best illustrated by an example:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) { return d.DiagnosisName; })
            .entries(json))
    .enter().append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "blue")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("cy", 150)
    .attr("cx", 0)
    .attr("r", 0)
    .each(function(d) {
        for(var i = 0; i < d.values.length; i++) {
            d3.select(this).transition().delay(1000 * i).duration(1000)
              .attr("r", function(d){return (d.values[i].VisitCount/10);})
              .attr("cx", function(d){return (d.values[i].Month * 100);});
        }
    });
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JSsHL/3/).

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that `dataset` does not contain any data. It is a call to a d3 function that does not return anything. However, you have this `csv` variable that you pass as an argument to the `drawChart` function.

You should thus write:

```
var circleGroup = svgContainer.append("g")
    .selectAll("circles")
    .data(csv)
```

Same for every time you use 'dataset' in a data() call.

If you have no data, then d3 does not plot anything. So looking at the data you attach when you have this kind of problem helps most of the times.

Also, `interpolateData` won't work for the same reason, you should probably pass `data` as an argument.

Comment: Thanks. I made this correction, but I'm still getting an empty DOM.

Comment: Then, please post a jsFiddle so we can try do debug your code.

Comment: ok, edited my post with my attempted JsFiddle... thank you for any time you might be able to look at this.